# Embedded PDF <object> does not show file in Internet Explorer and Edge

Tags: html, angularjs, object, internet-explorer, pdf

We are embedding a PDF document on the page using  the following:

```
<object ng-attr-data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{doc.DocumentBase64}}" 
                    type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;height:600px" />
```

{{doc.DocumentBase64}} will be replaced by a Base64 string of the PDF file contents.

The document shows up fine in Chrome and Firefox. However, in IE and Edge, it just shows a blank white area where the  is supposed to be.

Anything special that we are overlooking which needs to be done for IE & Edge when using  tag and data url is a base 64 string?

Comment: Checked the console?

Comment: Yes, nothing in the console. In Edge it just shows the blank white area with the height specified and in Internet Explorer it doesn't even show the element.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri says IE _"Support is limited to images and linked resources like CSS or JS, not HTML files."_ - might also exclude PDFs, have you tried to specifically research in that direction?

Comment: Ah, there we go then ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx _"Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or attributes: - object (images only) - ..."_

Comment: Got it, was not aware it wasn't supported, back to the drawing board :/